# Android : getting an item from a list (using onItemClick) and pass that Item data to another layout?

Tags: java, android, listview, onitemclicklistener

I've created list(containing name,mail,number,date) from server using listview extending by listactivity. And, i've also change the layout using list item by onItemClick. Now, i want to pass the values in these 4 column to 4 textviews(another layout). How can i do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: show the layout file you inflated to generate listview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would want to get the underlying data object by using the position parameter from the onItemClick() in the [getItem()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItem%28int%29) method of the adapter that you are using for the list ([getListAdapter()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#getListAdapter%28%29)); Then you'd just call setText on each of your TextViews to set the data there.

Comment: Thanks but, i want to pass these values to another layout's 4 textviews

Comment: what do you mean by a different layout? a different activity? A layout without a context doesn't do much.

Comment: I mean another layout. I've using one java file but 4 xml files.

Comment: well, in that case, inflate the other layout first, then find the textviews and then set their texts correctly?

Comment: and also i'm using jsonarray for listing the items. So, i need a brief explanation. i can't use your previous method.